# Prevent JavaScript/jQuery from reacting to mouse from under a higher stacked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running this plugin in WordPress that makes pretty image maps with shapes over images. It uses JS/jQuery extensively. I've used a custom script to show/hide a div when I click a shape. This particular div is stacked above the div that contains the image map. It appears and disappears just fine, but when I mouse over it and/or click on it, for some weird reason the hovers and clicks get through the higher stacked div down to the map div while still working on the popover one. Here's a simplified version of how things are set up:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.opacity == '1')
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.style.opacity = '0';
    }, this.animationDelay + 2),
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.style.zIndex = '-30';
    }, 400);
  else
    e.style.zIndex = '999999999',
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.style.opacity = '1';
    }, this.animationDelay + 2);
}
```

```css
.city {
  position: relative;
}

#ipano {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 90vw;
  left: 5vw;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -30;
}
```

```html
<div class="city">
  // map code
</div>

<div id="ipano">
  //popup code
</div>
```

The map plugin allows me to assign `onClick` code to any shape defined, so I added this to make a click on the shape reveal the hidden div like so: `toggle_visibility('ipano'); javascript:event.preventDeafult();`.

But even if I remove my custom script for revealing the `#ipano` div, the problem still persists. You can see it in action [here](https://agada.ga/map).

I think this is somehow due to the map script and how it handles the mapping of the overlay map regions (with an .svg), but I can't put my finger on it.

I've tried changing the divs' order, removing the preventDefault bit, and adding pointer-events: none; to some and all the map's elements, but that didn't help. How's that even possible?

Any suggestions in the right direction greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I can't see where are you registering the onclick event. I don't know if for this job would be better https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp and simply use onclick functions to the shapes but anyway, without looking how do you register events I guess you can prevent onclick for eg. checking if clickEvent.target.id !== 'divYouWantToignore'

Comment: I'm restricted to these plugins as per client's preferences. But even if I remove my JS for revealing the popover, and simply manually place it on top of the map, clicks/hovers are still going through it...

Comment: What about CSS property pointer-events - maybe plugin messes with it. - Check it.

Comment: I did play around with `pointer-events: none;` it doesn't affect any of the map's HTML elements.

Comment: This question lacks data like styling so no idea what covers what, plugin versions etc - provided code looks ok, but it's not enaugh to reproduce the problem. At this point we can't help you. Check the rules for posting minimal reproducable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example the best would be sandbox